# Скрыть токен telegram-бота в открытом коде

Tags: java, telegram-bot, telegram, token

Необходимо выложить код telegram-бота на GitHub. Каким образом можно скрыть его токен?

```
public String getBotToken() { return "token"; }
```

Comment: Хотите, чтобы токен был скрыт, но при сборке робот всё равно работал?

Обычно такие вещи выносят в конфигурационный файл, а в gitignore настраивают, чтобы данный файл не обновлялся

Comment: @АлексейОсецкий Если вас не затруднит - можете рассказать немного подробнее? Как назвать файл, в каком виде внести в него мой токен и как его оттуда вытащить?

Comment: Конечно, просто думал, что вы знаете данное решение, и ищете как именно скрыть, а не вынести в конфиг и попросить пользователя задать значение конфига

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Необходимо вынести токен в конфигурационный файл.
Конфигурационный файл должен находится в src/main/resources/config.properties
Содержание файла config.properties следующее:

```
# Токен необходимо задать при установке
token=
```

В таком виде конфигурационный файл закоммитить. После коммита можно будет вставить значение реального токена, чтобы была возможность запустить бота, но не коммитить значение

```
# Токен необходимо задать при установке
token=12344
```

Чтобы считывать токен из файла нужно воспользоваться классом import java.util.Properties;

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
try {
    //load a properties file from class path, inside static method
    prop.load(App.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties"));

    //get the property value and print it out
    System.out.println(prop.getProperty("token"));
} 
catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Чтобы в дальнейшем случайно не перезатереть файл с пустым токеном, реальным, который используется для разработки, нужно будет прописать файл config.properties в .gitignore

Comment: Большое спасибо!